# Building a jquery slideshow by changing the margin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create jquery slideshow from an array of images in php. I've got the html and css set up, but the javascript isn't doing anything. If what I am trying to do isn't possible or there is a better alternative route I'll happily take that advice. Any help would be appreciated!

PHP/HTML

```
$pic_array = array();
$titles = array();
$descriptions = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pic_array[$count] = $row['pic_url'];
    $titles[$count] = $row['title'];
    $descriptions[$count] = $row['description'];
    $count++;
}
echo "<div id='slider'>
        <ul class='slides'";
for ($x=0; $x < count($pic_array); $x++) {
    echo " <li class='slide'><img src= " . $dir . $pic_array[$x] . " /></li>";
}
echo "   </ul>  
      </div";
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width:10000px;
    height: 250px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
}
img {
    width: 450px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

    setInterval (function () {
        $('.slider .slides').animate({'margin-top':'-=250px'}, 1000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Why do you have two cycles there? You could put the content of the _for_ cycle into your _while_ cycle. No need for three arrays...

Comment: The three arrays are for the title description and picture and I guess I could merge the for and while loops but that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong jquery selector. It should be `$('#slider .slides')` because `slider` is an id, not a class.

Also, you are missing closing angle bracket in the `ul` element: `...<ul class='slides'>";` and in the `div#slider` element: `...</div>";`

Comment: Thanks for those catches, but for some reason it still does nothing.

Comment: You're also missing closing angle bracket when closing the div#slider tag, as I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I screwed up with all of that.

Comment: It's working but now when I change and save it the changes aren't there.. This might not be something that's in the code so I don't expect for you to know what's going on. If you've heard of this problem before an have possible solutions I would be grateful to here them.

Comment: I thought I figured it out, I wasn't connected to the VPN even though it said upload successful. I connected and the javascript still didn't change..